# given sentence how to generate grammatically correct, equivalent sentences

Tags: nlp

Using NLP how to generate similar sentences making use of a linguistic knowledge base.
I have tried using conceptnet to replace the nouns, verbs and adjectives. But the results are losing grammatical correctness, any technical advises would be a great help.